# SPEmailEventReceiver in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, event-receivers, visual-studio-2012, incoming-email

I'm stuck in use of SPEmailEventReceiver in sharepoint 2013.

this my code:

```
public class EREmail : SPEmailEventReceiver // this error because namespace can't found
{
    public override void EmailReceived(SPList list, SPEmailMessage emailMessage, String receiverData) // this error because namespace SPEmailMessage can't found
    {
        base.EmailReceived(list, emailMessage, receiverData);

    }
}
```

the above code produces error in both VS 2013 and VS 2012.

Any suggestion? help me

Comment: Have you done the Incoming email configuration ?.
For the List in which you want to store email, you need to do incoming email configuration.
It seems that you have not done it.
Please Use below link for email configuration <http://sharepoint.kerenapura.com/2014/03/set-incoming-emails-sharepoint-list/> <http://daniecsp.blogspot.in/2013/04/sp20132010-how-to-configure-incoming.html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running solution in sandbox type solution?

If so, try full trust type.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added both the using directives mentioned in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spemaileventreceiver.aspx)?

> This example requires using directives (Imports in Visual Basic) for
>   the Microsoft.SharePoint and Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities
>   namespaces.

It seems to not be enough to use Microsoft.SharePoint, you also need Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities

Comment: yes. i have add microsoft.sharepoint and microsoft.sharepoint.utilities namespaces. but still error. there is SPEmailEventReceiver in sharepoint 2013? in my solution sp2013.
i'm can't found SPEmailEventReceiver in sharepoint on object browser. in my solution sp2010. i found SPEmailEventReceiver on object browser.